# Material isn't showing in viewport or render

Tags: materials

I want a mirror sphere for a cool animation or something. I made a new texture using Glossy BSDF with 0.00 Roughness and the Preview for the material is perfect. The sphere however in the view port and rendered image is only reflecting the point light and not the environment. Any fix? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing this in eevee and for eevee you need to add Light probes for the reflections of the surrounding things so just press shift + a > Light probes > reflection cubemap 
add this on sphere and then go to indirect lighting menu in properties panel and bake the cubemap[image: Reflection cubemap]

and for more info on light probes just go to youtube and search for lightprobes and you will get tons of tutorials on it

Comment: I haven't even tried it yet but thanks for answering! <3